# Problem extracting values from an array of objects in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How can I only extract the property values from this array of object arrays and store them in a
new object arrangement?

I have this:

```
resp: [[{"property1":10}],[{"property2":20}],[{"property3":30}]];
```

but I want this so I can do an iteration of the values in a table.

```
resp: [{"property1":10,"property2":20,"property3":30}];
```

I've tried something like this but it doesn't work for me:

```
let test1 = success.resp[0];
let test2 = success.resp[1];
let test3 = success.resp[2];

let array: any = [{property1:test1,property2:test2,property3:test3}];
```

thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it in the following way, it's just a matter of seeing how I'm getting an answer, in my case it was a matrix.

```
let test1 = success.resp[0][0].property1;
let test2 = success.resp[1][0].property2;
let test3 = success.resp[2][0].property3;


let array: any[] = [{property1:test1,property1:test2,property3:test3}];

console.log("array: ",array);
```